# Workarounds to pre-populate fields in an LWC for Salesforce1

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app

I've been looking at the Spring '20 release where Salesforce introduced the new **lightning/pageReferenceUtils** module to be used alongside with **lightning/navigation** to pre-populate the fields when creating a new record. Here's a reference to it.

> https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lc_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm

I'm currently developing a LWC, trying to pre-populate a form with default values using the lightning/navigation. The problem is the pageReferenceUtils module's utilities for encoding and decoding default field values are not yet supported in the Salesforce1. Has anyone been able to find any workaround to that yet?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the older approach, which is compatible with Communities and (I presume) Salesforce Mobile, of using a URL addressable Aura component to address this functionality. [Doug Ayers](https://douglascayers.com) developed a generic component for this; take a look at his [GitHub](https://github.com/douglascayers/sfdx-record-create-url-component) resource.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution:

[Navigate to new record creation screen with pre-populated dynamic values.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375009/ive-built-an-object-agnostic-lwc-invoked-from-a-quick-action-that-prepopulates)

It involves a Quick Action tied to an LWC that inferfaces with an object-agnostic apex controller.

It also uses a custom metadata type to define your field mappings.