# I've built an object agnostic LWC invoked from a quick action that prepopulates default values on the new record creation screen. How can I improve it

Tags: lightning-web-components

My goal was to create an object agnostic Lightning Web Component/Quick Action solution that could be invoked from any record page and prepopulate default values on the record creation screen of a different Object. This goal emanated from the need to create a custom object record from the Opportunity record, via clicking a quick action, prepopulating the values from the Opportunity on the record creation screen before the record actually got created by the user clicking 'Save' within the modal.

I wanted to make the solution agnostic so I could easily reuse the same component each time I wanted to use it on a different object (and not have to write additional code). I want to both share this solution and see if there's any way I can improve it.

The solution uses a custom metadata type for the field mapping (to map source object to default value on destination object).

Solution in action:
[image]

**navToNewRecCreateModalWithDefaults.js**

```
// LWC used to prepopulate values on a record creation modal, invoked from a quick action
//
// Note: this LWC depends on the quick action API name being in the following format:
//  ObjectName_XXXXX_QuickActionName
//  Example: Quote_Request_c_XXXXX_New_Quote_Request_V2
//
// Note: if dealing with custom object, you cannot use __c in the naming convention above due to
//  Salesforce system limitation.
//  You must use _c, and then the Javascript in this LWC will fix it to reflect __c.
//  Do not use _c in any other part of the name.

import { LightningElement, api, wire } from "lwc";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import { encodeDefaultFieldValues } from "lightning/pageReferenceUtils";
import retrieveDefaultValues from "@salesforce/apex/DefaultValuesLwcController.retrieveDefaultValues";
import getFilesOnRecord from "@salesforce/apex/ApexUtils.getFilesOnRecord";
import { CurrentPageReference } from "lightning/navigation";

export default class DefaultValuesComponent extends NavigationMixin(
  LightningElement
) {
  sObjectApiName = "";
  quickActionAPIName = "";

  _recordId;
  retrievedRecordId = false;

  @wire(CurrentPageReference)
  getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
    // if the page is a quick action, get quick action API name
    if (currentPageReference.type === "standard__quickAction") {
      let quickActionPath = currentPageReference.attributes.apiName;
      let firstSplit = quickActionPath.split(".")[1];
      let sObjectApiName = firstSplit.split("_XXXXX_")[0];
      if (sObjectApiName.includes("_c")) {
        sObjectApiName = sObjectApiName.replace("_c", "__c");
      }
      this.sObjectApiName = sObjectApiName;
      this.quickActionAPIName = firstSplit.split("_XXXXX_")[1];
    }
  }

  @api set recordId(value) {
    this._recordId = value;
  }

  get recordId() {
    return this._recordId;
  }

  /**
   * Renderedcallback to call our main method to navigate to new quote request record creation screen and load defaults
   */
  renderedCallback() {
    if (!this.retrievedRecordId && this.recordId) {
      this.retrievedRecordId = true; // Escape case from recursion
      this.retrieveDefaultValuesMethod();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Method to perform the retrieval of default values from the opportunity/business and populate
   *  those in the Quote Request record creation form
   */
  retrieveDefaultValuesMethod() {
    const quickActionApiName = String(this.quickActionAPIName);
    // call apex controller method to retrieve the default values:
    retrieveDefaultValues({
      recordId: this.recordId,
      quickActionApiNameParam: quickActionApiName
    })
      .then((result) => {
        const defaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues(result);
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
          type: "standard__objectPage",

          attributes: {
            objectApiName: this.sObjectApiName,
            actionName: "new"
          },

          state: {
            defaultFieldValues: defaultValues
          }
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Error querying record",
            message: error.body.message,
            variant: "error",
            mode: "sticky"
          })
        );
      });
  }
}
```

**navToNewRecCreateModalWithDefaults.html:**

```
<template>
  <div style="display: none">{recordId}</div>
</template>
```

**navToNewRecCreateModalWithDefaults.js-meta.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>53.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Navigate and populate defaults</masterLabel>
    <description
  >Navigate to New Record Recreation screen from a quick action, and populate default values on that screen</description>
    <targets>
      <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
      <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
        <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
      </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

**DefaultValuesLwcController.cls:**

```
public class DefaultValuesLwcController {
    private static String quickActionApiName;
    private static String parentObjectName;

    /**
     * @description: singleton method to query default values
     * @return defaultValueFieldMappings (List<Default_Value_Field_Mapping__mdt>: a list of default value pairs
     */
    private static List<Default_Value_Field_Mapping__mdt> defaultValueFieldMappings {
        get {
            if (defaultValueFieldMappings == null) {
                defaultValueFieldMappings = [
                    SELECT Parent_Object_Field__c, Target_Object_Field__c
                    FROM Default_Value_Field_Mapping__mdt
                    WHERE Quick_Action_API_Name__c = :quickActionApiName AND Parent_Object_Name__c = :parentObjectName
                ];
            }
            return defaultValueFieldMappings;
        }
        set;
    }

    /**
     * @description: method to map the target field to the associated queried value from the parent object
     * @param record (SObject): the queried parent record
     * @param quickActionApiName (String): the name of the quick action interfacing with this controller
     * @return the queried record
     */
    private static Map<String, String> getDefaultValuesFieldMap(SObject record, String quickActionApiName) {
        Map<String, String> defaultValuesFieldMap = new Map<String, String>();
        for (Default_Value_Field_Mapping__mdt dvfm : defaultValueFieldMappings) {
            Object fieldValueObj = record.get(dvfm.Parent_Object_Field__c);
            String parentObjFieldValue;
            if (fieldValueObj instanceof Date) {
                parentObjFieldValue = String.valueOf((Date) record.get(dvfm.Parent_Object_Field__c));
            } else {
                parentObjFieldValue = String.valueOf(record.get(dvfm.Parent_Object_Field__c));
            }
            defaultValuesFieldMap.put(dvfm.Target_Object_Field__c, parentObjFieldValue);
        }
        return defaultValuesFieldMap;
    }

    /**
     * @description: method to query custom fields, since the out-of-box lwc getRecords can't do it effectively
     * @param recordId (Id): Id of the record to query
     * @param quickActionApiName (String): the name of the quick action invoking this apex method
     * @return the queried record
     */
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Map<String, String> retrieveDefaultValues(Id recordId, String quickActionApiNameParam) {
        System.debug('DefaultValuesLwcController.retrieveDefaultValues quickActionApiNameParam: ' + quickActionApiNameParam);
        try {
            quickActionApiName = quickActionApiNameParam;
            parentObjectName = String.valueOf(recordId.getSobjectType());
            List<String> fieldsToQuery = new List<String>();
            for (Default_Value_Field_Mapping__mdt dvfm : defaultValueFieldMappings) {
                fieldsToQuery.add(dvfm.Parent_Object_Field__c);
            }

            String queryString = 'SELECT ' + String.join(fieldsToQuery, ', ') + ' FROM ' + parentObjectName + ' WHERE Id = :recordId';
            System.debug('DefaultValuesLwcController.retrieveDefaultValues queryString: ' + queryString);
            SObject record = Database.query(queryString);

            return getDefaultValuesFieldMap(record, quickActionApiName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('DefaultValuesLwcController.retrieveDefaultValues exception: ' + e.getMessage() + ', ' + e.getStackTraceString());
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good job, and thanks for sharing, but I'm not totally sure if this type of post is a good fit. It might be more appropriate on the Code Review SE.

Comment: @AdrianLarson thanks for the tip!

Comment: Very helpful post. Could you please explain how you got the redirect to open inside the modal? Is it your renderedCallback? I have a similar LWC that closes the modal and redirects in a new tab.